# What do 인 사상 and 다 싶으리 mean in the passage below?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I have a text as follows:

> 그러나 이 중에서 현대 한국인들의 사고에 큰 영향을 끼치고 있는 사상은 뭐니 뭐니 해도 조선 시대의 국교였던 유교라고 할 수 있다. 유교는 중국의 춘추 시대에 살았던 사상가 공자(기원전 551~479년)의 사상을 기본으로 한다. 공자는 첫째로, 항상 어진 마음을 가지고 생활해야 한다는 **인 사상**과 둘째로, 인간이 지켜야 할 도덕과 윤리를 지켜야 한다는 윤리 사상,그리고 마지막으로,나라 에 충성하고 부모에게 효도하는 것을 기대하는 충효 사상을 주장하였다.
>
> 이러한 유교 사상의 영향으로 조선 시대에는 돌아가신 조상님에 대한 제사와, 일상생활에서의 예절, 그리고 가족을 이루는 혈연이 **지나치다 싶으리만큼** 매우 중시되었다"

I have 2 questions regarding this passage.

What does 인 사상 mean? I looked for this word in the dictionary but couldn't find it.

In the phrase 지나치다 싶으리만큼, what is the "다 싶으리" structure used for? I have never seen this structure before.

Comment: A quick answer to the first question: https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/d53cf744f1dc4aafa2087748da9c0849 more specifically https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/6ea9f903f10544f4ad06cbb1d31641db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 인 사상 is the idea of forgiveness and benevolence originating from Confucius (공자).  The character 인(仁) is called '어질 인', where 어질 the meaning part is the adjectival form of 어질다 (loving and forgiving). It was one of the well respected ideas in the old Joseon (조선) dynasty.
2. 싶으리만큼 is about the same as 싶을 만큼 (so ... as to ...), but it sounds smoother and more indirect and polite (으리 generally sounds more flowy than 을).

Verb/Adj-다 싶을 만큼 is -다 싶다 connected with -(으)ㄹ 만큼 (so ... as to / enough to).  It is one of two major uses of 싶다.

- Verb-고 싶다 = want to Verb / feel like Verb-ing.  => expresses a specific desire.
- Verb/Adj-다 싶다 (and similar constructs) = it appears/feels that (they are doing/being ...) => expresses a faint feeling, suspicion or judgement.

The second 싶다 is very flexible and can connect with many different verb/adj forms, as in -(ㅆ)다 싶다 (mild judgement about what one/someone does/has done), -(ㅆ)나 싶다/-(ㅆ)는가 싶다 (unsure guess about what is/was happening), -(으)ㄹ까 싶다 (what one feels one/others might do), -야지 싶다 (thoughts on what must be done), and so on.  The important point is that there is -고 싶다 which is a distinctive construct, and all other cases of 싶다 which can be lumped in one as different from -고 싶다.

So 그리고 가족을 이루는 혈연이 **지나치다 싶으리만큼** 매우 중시되었다 = And the blood relations forming a family was regarded as so very important **as to come off as going overboard**.